# Why can't my recyclerview scroll completely

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get recyclerview to scroll completely. For some reason the recyclerview stops to scroll at a particular spot, as if it as scrolled completedly.

Here's a picture of this:
[image: Image reflecting the question]

Please keep in mind this is where the recyclerview scrolls to. And this fragment (screen) only contains the recyclerview.

this is the layout of the fragment containing the recyclerview:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.ways.WaysFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/custom_ways_item" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This the custom_view_item of the recyclerview:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="425dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        .....

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.. I'm more than happy to provide any information needed. Thanks again.

**EDIT**

Here's my activity_main.xml. I'm using navigation component method.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/container"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: How is the bottom navigation bar included in your layout? Is it also part of the `ConstraintLayout` holding your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @BenP. The naviagtion bar is on the main_activty's xml file I'm using navigation component method. And I have added the file above

Answer (score 1):

The `RecyclerView` (fragment content) is drawn behind the `BottomNavView`; to solve this you need to make the fragment container to match the constraints by setting `android:layout_height="0dp"`; so that the constraints set can be applied:

```
 <fragment
    ... 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the recycler view a `layout_height` of **0dp** so it can match constraints also link the bottom constraint to top of the bottom navigation menu.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_nav_menu" />
```